# View not found after returning parameters to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

My controller works fine and returns the right view when hit without a parameter, however when i pass in parameter to the action, the view is not found. The controller is in an area called Admin and the route registration is displayed below

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get { return "Admin"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ZedvancePortal.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

The RouteConfig.cs in the appstart folder

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ZedvancePortal.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

The area is registered in the Global.asax page. This is the controller action below.

```
public ActionResult Review(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    var model = _db.Applications.Include(a => a.ApplicationStatus).OrderByDescending(a => a.ApplicationDate);
    if (start != null && end != null)
    {
        model = model.Where(a => a.ApplicationDate >= start && a.ApplicationDate <= end).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ApplicationDate);
    }
    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

On first load, without the start and end parameters passed from the Review.cshtml view, it loads correctly. However when i pass in those parameters and try to return the parameter filtered result to that same view i get the error

> The view 'Review' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/ApplicationReview/Review.aspx
>   ~/Views/ApplicationReview/Review.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Review.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Review.ascx ~/Views/ApplicationReview/Review.cshtml
>   ~/Views/ApplicationReview/Review.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Review.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Review.vbhtml

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the model type match for your Review View?

Comment: is this one is a post method or get method

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan i'm using a post method to submit the parameter to the Review action

Comment: @CaptainAnon yes the model matches. In the action i'm returning a model of type ZedvancePortal.Models.Application which i return an IEnumerable of it in the view

Comment: @ibnhamza Have you specified controller name and action method name in Html.Begin form?

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan yes i specified it judging  by the fact that the submitted parameters were accurately passed to the action, only problem is when returning the view based on the result of the data request.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is Because if you mention only Name of View,it results in `Ambiguity` because it found an `Web service` and `View`,and will an Error to avoid Confusion

Try using Full Path of View i.e like

```
return View("~/Views/ApplicationReview/Review.cshtml",model.ToList());
```

Comment: i dont think i understand you. I'm returning "model.ToList()" in the action. There is no mention to the view name in the action